# Adding reverted commits back to main / master branch in Github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I had a branch `test` which I merged to `master` branch.

After the merge, I identified that there was an issue with my code and so reverted the commits associated with `test` branch.

Now if I merge changes from `master` to `test` branch , the changes in the `test` branch are overwritten as I believe `master` is considered to be the latest.

Is there a way for me to add the required fix in `test` branch and merge it back to `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to avoid merging integration branches (like `master`, which receives merges from multiple branches, to integrate them) to topic branches (like `test`).

Ideally, you would fix the issue in `test` first, then merge test (again) to `master`, to report the fix.

In your case, since you worked on master first, you might consider rebasing `test` on top of the new `master` (and force pushing test).
`test` (once rebased) will then be ready to be merged again later on to `master`.

Comment: To "merge (again)" the test branch will not undo the reverted commits, unfortunately. The reversals have to be reverted, too.

Comment: @j6t Yes, I was describing the optimal path (meaning the revert was not done, and the fix applied directly in test)